# Shiny plot not rendering in client-side dynamic UI

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny

I'm trying to render some UI elements in Shiny on the client side using Javascript. I want the user to click a button which reveals a hidden panel. Once the panel is revealed, it should show a plot. When the button is clicked the panel becomes visible but the plot doesn't render.

I know this behaviour is achievable using server-side functions like `observeEvent` but the goal here is to leverage the client directly via JS.

Below is a reprex. For ease, I've inlined the JS and CSS.

```
library(shiny)

# Inline js to toggle display of element when button is clicked
js <- '
  $(document).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById("reveal").addEventListener("click", event => {
      var panel = document.getElementById("init-hidden-panel");
      panel.style.display = "block";
    });
  })
  '

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  tags$script(HTML(js)),
  
  actionButton("reveal", "Reveal"),
  
  div(
    id = "init-hidden-panel",
    plotOutput("plot"),
    style = "display: none; background-color: darkgray" # initialize element as hidden
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(iris$Sepal.Length)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

We can tell that the JS is in fact toggling the display because the gray background appears.

Comment: You can try to add `outputOptions(output, "plot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)` in the server.

Comment: That works! As always @StéphaneLaurent, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use this method:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("reveal", "Reveal"),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  plot_data <- reactiveValues(trigger = 0)
  
  observe({
    req(input$reveal)
    isolate(plot_data$trigger <- plot_data$trigger + 1)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    input$reveal
    if (plot_data$trigger %% 2 == 0) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      hist(iris$Sepal.Length)
    }
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't do what I want. I'm specifically looking for a client-side solution that uses Javascript to handle the display of the panel. I'm trying to avoid processing using the server side (i.e., via R)